# Default application to choose file

Tags: android, audio, filechooser

[image]

I'm using the following code to load an audio file:

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent chooseFile;
            Intent intent;
            chooseFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            chooseFile.setType("audio/*");
            intent = Intent.createChooser(chooseFile, "Choose a file");
            startActivityForResult(intent, ONE);

        }
```

This presents me with the above screen, but when the user uses an app like AndroidZip or any file managers the app crashes. How do I set "Select Music Track", which is native to android, as the default choice?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `ndroid.content.Intent.ACTION_PICK` action.

Besides, I don't exactly sure that "Select Music Track" activity is always present in every Android device.

You can also query the `PackageManager` on which packages handle the action you require and then based on the reply, you apply filtering and then fire the Intent you want with a Activity you want.